# Refresh a data bound Grid View in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView which is bound to a datasource. First column of GridView is Serial #. When user randomly deletes a record from the GridView, I want the S# column to auto refresh. Like records are in this order 1,2,3,4,5. If I delete 3rd record, serial # should become 1,2,3,4.

I have tried to call

```
GridView.DataBound();
```

But this does not help.

Comment: Can you show us some more of your code and add some more detail to your question?

Comment: Also take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just for display, not for changing the serial number in the database, try a TemplateField column like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial No" >
   <ItemTemplate>    
       <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex + 1%>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Much cleaner. I learned something today :) it's a good day, I withdraw my answer